# SQL SUM and CASE

Tags: sql, sum, case

I have a LineItem table.

```
InvoiceNo   ApplyTax(bool)   Subtotal  
1              1                10
1              0                10  
1              1                10 
2              0                10
2              1                10
```

Apply Tax means adding another 7% to subtotal

I need a select statement that returns.

```
InvoiceNo     Total
1              31.4 ----(10* 1.07 + 10 + 10*1.07)
2              20.7 ----(  10* 1.07 + 10)
```

I could come up with this but its giving syntax error.

```
SELECT InvoiceNo ,SUM(( select case(ApplyTax) WHEN 1 THEN 1.07 ELSE 1)*subtotal) 
From InvoiceTable
Group By InvoiceNo
```

Am i missing something really simple? I can't get it right.

Comment: Anyway, why not you just * 1.07 since 0 * 1.07 = 0. So ends up you're still getting 0. Why waste extra processing for 'case'.

Comment: case 1 = true and case 0 = false. When true, you apply tax, if its false you don't apply. Its either something * 1.07 or something * 1 not the other way around. @Sky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper syntax:

```
SELECT InvoiceNo, SUM((case ApplyTax WHEN 1 THEN 1.07 ELSE 1 end)*subtotal) 
From InvoiceTable
Group By InvoiceNo ;
```

Notice there is no nested `select` statement and the `case` ends with `end`.

Comment: Ok, found the answer been reading it wrongly silly me. 

http://weblogs.asp.net/wilczynski/archive/2008/06/03/sum-case-in-sql.aspx

    Select InvoiceNo ,SUM(  case When ApplyTax = '1' THEN 1.07 *subtotal ELSE subtotal END)
    From InvoiceTable
    Group By InvoiceNo

Comment: YEA! THANKS. I've been look at it. IT WORKED. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Put `END` at the end of your `CASE` statement..

```
SELECT inv ,SUM(( select case(ApplyTax) WHEN 1 THEN 1.07 ELSE 1 END)*subtotal) as total
From test 
Group By inv
```